# Make left and right navbars absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to make the left and right navbars fixed according to content and **browser-size**. I mean left navbar always should be on the left side **with enough space between the content.** Likewise, the right navbar always should be on the right side **with enough space between content.** (Even I shrink the size of the browser)

My left navbar is ok. There is enough space between left navbar and content and if I shrink the size of the browser there is still enough space between those. However, when I shrink the size of the browser, **right navbar overlaps on the content.** When you run the code snippet, you will see the problem.

Changing HTML layout is absolutely unnecessary. It is all about **CSS positioning!**.

```css
body {
 background-color: #2da157;
 font-family: Verdana;
}

.content {
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 200px;
 height:auto;
 width: 70%;
 background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
 color: gray;
}

h2 {
 color:#2da157;
}

h3 {
 color: #2da157;
}

#leftnav {
 margin-top: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px dotted black;
 top:0px;
}

#rightnav {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 150px;
 background-color: gray;
 border: 2px dotted black;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 top: 0px;
 right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>positioning test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>welcome to my web site</h1>
            <p>Here is a place for some intro text about my web site. I normally have lots to say, but right now I'm at a loss. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto.</p>
            <p>Why don't we try another topic...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>about the class</h2>
            <p>This class has been fantastic! The students are the best students ever. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>one more box</h2>
            <p>Everything we add to this page adds nicely boxed and centred material down the middle of the page. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto.</p>
            <p>Ain't CSS great?</p>
        </div>
        <div id="leftnav">
            <h2>some links</h2>
            <p><a href="#">fake link one</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">also fake</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">artificial</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">goes nowhere</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">big faker</a></p>
            <h2>external links</h2>
            <p><a href="http://www.google.ca">Google</a></p>
            <p><a href="http://www.cbc.ca">CBC</a></p>
            <p><a href="http://www.nfl.com">NFL</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightnav">
            <h2>why are you here?</h2>
            <p>Why have you come to my site?</p>
            <p>Perhaps you wish to know more about me.</p>
            <p>Or more about CSS? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto.</p>
            <p>Go away.</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply apply correct margin to content on both left and right side and no need to specify any width or left property:

```css
body {
  background-color: #2da157;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  color: gray;
}

h2 {
  color: #2da157;
}

h3 {
  color: #2da157;
}

#leftnav {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px dotted black;
  top: 0px;
}

#rightnav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px dotted black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>welcome to my web site</h1>
  <p>Here is a place for some intro text about my web site. I normally have lots to say, but right now I'm at a loss. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy
    ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto.</p>
  <p>Why don't we try another topic...</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h2>about the class</h2>
  <p>This class has been fantastic! The students are the best students ever. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy
    adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto.</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h2>one more box</h2>
  <p>Everything we add to this page adds nicely boxed and centred material down the middle of the page. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto.</p>
  <p>Ain't CSS great?</p>
</div>
<div id="leftnav">
  <h2>some links</h2>
  <p><a href="#">fake link one</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">also fake</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">artificial</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">goes nowhere</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">big faker</a></p>
  <h2>external links</h2>
  <p><a href="http://www.google.ca">Google</a></p>
  <p><a href="http://www.cbc.ca">CBC</a></p>
  <p><a href="http://www.nfl.com">NFL</a></p>
</div>
<div id="rightnav">
  <h2>why are you here?</h2>
  <p>Why have you come to my site?</p>
  <p>Perhaps you wish to know more about me.</p>
  <p>Or more about CSS? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy ibid lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy adipiscing atet prosciutto.</p>
  <p>Go away.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask something? I try to understand CSS positioning. In this case, I specified position: absolute for both left and right navbar, and I thought I need to specify position: relative to the content because absolute positioning will be aligned according to content?

Comment: @newbie35 position:relative should be specified to the container of the element you made absolute and not the content in this case ...